# mobaxterm 12.4 X11-forwarding is not working for the new VM

Tags: soa, xserver, mobaxterm

i am using MObaXterm 12.4  for GUI installation but getting the below display error, and installation wizard was not opening due to display error.

but the same mobaxtrem gui is working fine for another VM, what are the packages need to install for the linux machine? i tried the with export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0.

any suggestions ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure xorg-x11-xauth is installed
and need to placed the entry of X11Forwarding yes in this file /etc/ssh/sshd_config.